# Import Jar in Talend Component

Tags: java, jar, components, etl, talend

I am writing a component for TOS DI and therefor I need to import a JAR.
In the component xml ist says:

```
 <CODEGENERATION> 
<IMPORTS> 
  <IMPORT MODULE="tHelloWorld-0.1.jar" NAME="tHelloWorld-0.1" UrlPath="D:\Program Files\TOS_DI-20170623_1246-V6.4.1\plugins\org.talend.libraries.custom_6.4.1.20170623_1246\lib\tHelloWorld-0.1.jar" REQUIRED="true"/> 
</IMPORTS>  </CODEGENERATION>
```

The _begin.javajet imports my Jar:

```
<%@ jet 
imports="
    org.talend.core.model.process.INode 
    org.talend.core.model.process.ElementParameterParser 
    org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataTable 
    org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataColumn 
    org.talend.core.model.process.IConnection
    org.talend.core.model.process.IConnectionCategory
    org.talend.designer.codegen.config.CodeGeneratorArgument
    org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaTypesManager
    org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaType
    java.util.List 
    java.util.Map       
    MyHelloWorld.tHelloWorld.App
" %>
```

The jar I want to import simply offers a method sayHello() that prints "Hello World".
The Jar itself lies in the component folder and in the  \org.talend.libraries.custom_6.4.1.20170623_1246 folder. When I first used the component I was asked to import the Jar and I told it the path where my Jar lies. I also added the Jar to the Java Build Path.

Everytime I start the job I get the error message "The import MyHelloWorld cannot be resolved".

Do you have any idea what I can do for that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I was able to resolve this question. You need to delet the imports and write the package structure in front of the class you want to use. Furthermore you need to call it outside <%%>.

Comment: Do you still need to import the library with the load library component or is it already available?

Comment: i believe you are missing tLibraryLoad component. use this component to load your jar

Comment: thanks for your answer. The tLibraryLoad component works fine (so it is not the jar) but I want to write a component that integrates external tools to TOS and therefor the tLibraryLoad is the wrong solution. Is there any other thing?